# App font changes while changing mobile font

Tags: java, android

So I have a problem in my Application, and that is when I am overriding default mobile font in my app then it's working fine but when I apply a theme to my phone then my app's font family changes. Kindly find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily.

1. Go to your styles.xml or themes.xml depending on your version
2. In your `AppTheme`, type `<item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>`

Done! Comment if any problem
[

Note: it will work on API 26+.

Comment: I have already tried this.... It's just overrideing only default font... But not mobile theme font... My mobile Huawei font...

Comment: This option is for API 26 and above. Not 16+